# Unicode support in requests

Tags: python, unicode, request

I'm using `requests` library to read a text file from URL like:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://example.com/file.txt')
result = list(response.text.splitlines())
```

But some lines of a file contain Unicode characters (Slavic symbols).
Then I cant use this string properly as it appears corrupted after being read.
What is the proper approach for such a case?

Comment: Figure out the correct encoding, then use `response.content.decode('some-encoding')`

Comment: It worked for me with `response.content.decode('utf-8')`, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. I expanded upon this in the answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.text` is powered by `response.encoding`, which, in the absence of a proper `Content-type: ...; charset=...` header, is guessed by the `chardet` or `charset_normalizer` modules internally by Requests (and exposed as `response.apparent_encoding`). (This guesswork is due to be deprecated in a later version of Requests, as far as I know.)

On occasion that autodetection fails and you'll get gibberish (as you do), and you'll need to figure out what the encoding is yourself, and either:

- do `response.content.decode('some-encoding')`, or
- set `response.encoding = 'some-encoding'`, after which `response.text` will use that encoding.